# Implementing bool() without any conditionals

Tags: code-challenge

Title says it all. Given some input, turn it into a boolean value (0 or 1), without using conditional statements (e.x. `== > < <= >= != ~=`), or any function which uses conditional statements within its implementation, such as `if`, `while` and `for`. Your program must work with floating points, although you get more if it works with other items.

A general rule for determining whether `bool(item)` is False is if the item is empty (`''` is an empty string, `[]` is an empty list.), or if the function used to turn an item of one type into another is given no input (in Python, `str()` returns `''`, `list()` returns `[]`.)

Here are (some of) the different valid types. Your program is considered to work with one type if it works with one item in the following lists:

- Integers, floating points, doubles, longs
- Strings
- Lists, tuples, arrays (bytearrays)
- Dictionaries
- Functions
- Objects/Classes

Program score will be calculated like this: `[# of characters]-(50*[# of types])`. The program with the smallest score wins the challenge.

Comment: This problem is deceptively difficult. Perhaps a more concise wording would be to disallow any language construct which passively performs a boolean conversion (as `&&`, `||`, `while`, `for(;foo;)`, etc. all do).

Comment: Would you give an example of valid input that does *not* use comparison operators (such as == > < <- >= !=)? I must be missing something. It seems to me that they are essential elements of the sorts of propositions one wishes to assess.

Comment: How do you measure how many types you handle?  Do types such as float/double count as a single floating-point type or two separate types?

Comment: @MrZander: I would consider a double as a float, since everything that works with doubles will work with floats too.

Comment: How can this possibly be language-agnostic? The problem definition makes various assumptions that seem to tie it to Python and close relatives, and the scoring system lets some languages claim a score of -Infinity.

Comment: @PeterTaylor as I understand it, there are only 7 different 'types' possible, ergo a maximum (or rather, minimum) of -350 bonus. Although, I do agree that Set/Frozenset only applies to very few languages, and probably shouldn't be included.

Comment: @primo: I have removed sets. I have only used Python for programming, so I have no knowledge of other programming languages :P

Comment: I suppose PHPs `settype` is disallowed? :)

Comment: @Leigh: Haha, yes it is disallowed.

Answer (score 8):

## Python - 122 chars - 50*13 types = -528

```
def b(x=False):
 try:return[False][x]
 except IndexError:return True
 except:
  try:return b(len(x))
  except:return True
```

Works for the following built-in types (as listed in [§3.2 The standard type hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy))

1. NotImplemented
2. Ellipsis
3. int
4. long
5. bool
6. string
7. unicode
8. tuple
9. list
10. bytearray
11. set
12. frozenset
13. dict

Comment: Using exceptions to emulate conditionals... seems to simple, in retrospect ;)

Comment: What you have there seems to be 121 characters, not 122 :) Also, you can save one more character by `pass`ing instead of returning `True` and then doing that at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, -278

```
function bool(_,$){try{$=_.length;$._;_=$}catch(_){}return 1-isNaN(_/_)}
```

Doesn’t use any boolean operators! If global leaking and input is okay, then it’s even shorter, at 65 characters:

```
bool=eval.bind(0,'try{$=_.length;$._;_=$}catch(_){}1-isNaN(_/_)')
```

Works for anything with a `length` and all primitive types and their object wrappers.

Now you've added a list of things that count as types, but what kind of function or class should evaluate to `false`? This one treats functions that take no arguments as `false` - does that count? What about classes? What does that mean?

Comment: You have numbers, strings, arrays and dictionaries, functions, and object; giving you the best bonus: -350.  So, your score is **-278**.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Ah, the question was updated. Thanks. But it doesn't work with functions. (Well, it *does*, but what's an "empty" function anyways? This one will detect a function that takes no arguments.)

Answer (score 2):

## MMIX (8 bytes assembled)

Assembly language has no statements.

```
bool    ZSNZ $0,$0,1
        POP  1,0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Scala(152 characters)

```
implicit def?(a:Any)={val f=false;a match{case 0=>f;case null=>f;case ""=>f;case ()=>f;case None=>f;case x:Iterable[_]=>x.exists(_=>true)case _=>true}}
```

Sample inputs:

```
scala> if(0) true else false
res0: Boolean = false

scala> if(0.0) true else false
res1: Boolean = false

scala> if(1) true else false
res2: Boolean = true

scala> if(()) true else false
res3: Boolean = false

scala> if(List()) true else false
res4: Boolean = false

scala> if(List(1)) true else false
res5: Boolean = true

scala> if(Set()) true else false
res6: Boolean = false

scala> if("") true else false
res7: Boolean = false

scala> if(Map()) true else false
res8: Boolean = false
   
scala> if(None) true else false
res9: Boolean = false

scala> class X
defined class X

scala> if(new X()) true else false
res10: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0):

### **GoRuby, 19 - 50*(number of types in Ruby)**

```
def bool(o)
   [1,[o].fle.j.sz].mi
end
```

Returns 0 if the passed object converts to the empty string, 1 otherwise.  Of course, Ruby doesn't treat 0 as false, so this isn't a very *useful* function...in fact, `bool(bool(x))` is always 1.  Objects that do convert to 0 include `nil`,`false`,`[]`, and lists containing only objects that convert to 0.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 85 chars - 50*20 types = -915 points

```
def b(x=False):
 try:return b(len(x))
 except:return{0:False,None:False}.get(x,True)
```

So it works for all types in the six categories in the question.
The score is therefore 85 - 50*6 = -215, or am I wrong?

Here is also my test code:

```
class Test(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

for x in [None, NotImplemented, Ellipsis, 
    0,1,0L,1L,False,True,0.0,1.0,0.0j,1.0j,
    '','a',u'',u'a',
    (),(1,),[],[1],bytearray(),bytearray('31'),
    set(),set('ab'),frozenset(),frozenset('ab'),
    {},{'a':0},b, Test, Test.__init__,(a for a in 'a')]:
  print b(x), bool(x), type(x)
```

Think I've forgotten some types ;-)

```
b(x) bool(x) type(x)
False False <type 'NoneType'>
True True <type 'NotImplementedType'>
True True <type 'ellipsis'>
False False <type 'int'>
True True <type 'int'>
False False <type 'long'>
True True <type 'long'>
False False <type 'bool'>
True True <type 'bool'>
False False <type 'float'>
True True <type 'float'>
False False <type 'complex'>
True True <type 'complex'>
False False <type 'str'>
True True <type 'str'>
False False <type 'unicode'>
True True <type 'unicode'>
False False <type 'tuple'>
True True <type 'tuple'>
False False <type 'list'>
True True <type 'list'>
False False <type 'bytearray'>
True True <type 'bytearray'>
False False <type 'set'>
True True <type 'set'>
False False <type 'frozenset'>
True True <type 'frozenset'>
False False <type 'dict'>
True True <type 'dict'>
True True <type 'function'>
True True <type 'type'>
True True <type 'instancemethod'>
True True <type 'generator'>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash

Bash only does integer arithmetic of numbers stored in strings.  So this isn't really a proper answer as there are no floats.  But I thought this was an interesting integer-only solution:

```
$ bool () { echo $(( (($1 * $1) + 2) % (($1 * $1) + 1) )); }
$ for i in {-5..5}; do bool $i; done
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
$
```

Answer (score -2):

### Perl, 5 char

```
1-!$x
```

Works for integers, floating-point values, strings, and C. Although in Perl, these are all the same type.

Comment: ! is a boolean operation